# How to display button flyout in call out style, windows 8 xaml c#?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8.1

I have an info button in my windows 8 app, when I click on that button I have to display the information in call out style. In silverlight controls I have found call out controls, but how can I achieve in my windows 8 xaml c# app?

Here is my xaml code:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource infoButtonStyle}"
                  >
            <Button.Flyout   >
                <Flyout Placement="Right" >
                    <StackPanel >
                        <TextBlock Width="280" Text="This is a detailed description" FontSize="16"
                       FontWeight="SemiLight" FontFamily="Segoe UI" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Margin="0,0,0,10"  />

                    </StackPanel>
                    <Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="FlyoutPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.ZoomMode" Value="Enabled"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="LightGray"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="100"/>
                            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="300"/>

                        </Style>
                    </Flyout.FlyoutPresenterStyle>
                </Flyout>
            </Button.Flyout>
        </Button>
```

Comment: Your Win8 xaml is going to be very similar (if not identical) to SL xaml. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

A few libraries on the web, provides a "Flyout" control that you can use.
The difference between winrt and your current code, is that you will have to create a Flyout control, then open it, using the "Click" event, or a command binding, on the button you want to use to achieve that.

The syntax will be slightly different, but you can find plenty of examples.

Take a look at the Callisto Winrt controls, and you will find what you're looking for.